# Почему не удаляется атрибут disabled у кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.

Есть форма.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cabinet/registration" style="font-size: 16px;">

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" name="registration" class="registration_submit" id="registration" disabled />
    </form>
```

Есть скрипт на Javascript, который проверяет, не пустые ли поля:

```
function checkParams() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var re_password = $('#re_password').val();

    if(email.length != 0 && password.length != 0 && re_password.length != 0) {
        $('#registration').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#registration').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, почему не удаляется атрибут disabled у кнопки. Хотя в условия входит все нормально!

Comment: уберите из тегов `onkeyup=...` и вместо этого назначайте после определения ф-ии:

    $('#email').on('keyup', checkParams);

Comment: В смысле? Скрипт так-то работает, я поставил в условия Alert, он выводится! Проблема где-то в этой строчке:

    $('#registration').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: @duddeniska, disabled, selected и аналоги управляются через `.prop()`

Comment: Так мне нужно удалить attr и все!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242205/removeattr-not-removing-disabled-attribute-in-ie

Comment: @duddeniska, я вам написал ответ на этот самый ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Всё и так у вас прекрасно работает!

```js
function checkParams() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var re_password = $('#re_password').val();

    if(email.length != 0 && password.length != 0 && re_password.length != 0) {
        $('#registration').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#registration').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cabinet/registration" style="font-size: 16px;">

            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="password" name="re_password" id="re_password" value="" onkeyup='checkParams()'/>

            <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" name="registration" class="registration_submit" id="registration" disabled />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем jQuery, когда у HTMLInputElement есть нативные нативные свойства 'disabled' и 'value'?

```
   var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
   ...
       document.getElementById('registration').disabled = ...;
```

Comment: Действительно, зачем эти фреймворки все. Пообколются себе фреймворками по подъездам и думают потом абстракциями.